# Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Em uma aplicação **nodejs** recebo esta mensagem de erro:

**Versão:**

node: 8.9.2

npm: 5.5.1

express: 4.15.5

**Imagem do erro:**

[image: imagem do erro]

**Codigo do app.js**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/users');
var path = require('path');

var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var errorhandler = require('errorhandler')

var app = express();



//load customers route
var customers = require('./routes/customers'); 
var app = express();

var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4300);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var logger = require('morgan');
app.use(logger)

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(errorhandler());
}

/*------------------------------------------
    connection peer, register as middleware
    type koneksi : single,pool and request 
-------------------------------------------*/

app.use(

    connection(mysql,{

        host: 'localhost', //'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password : '',
        port : 3306, //port mysql
        database:'nodejs'

    },'pool') //or single

);





app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/customers', customers.list);
app.get('/customers/add', customers.add);
app.post('/customers/add', customers.save);
app.get('/customers/delete/:id', customers.delete_customer);
app.get('/customers/edit/:id', customers.edit);
app.post('/customers/edit/:id',customers.save_edit);


app.use(app.router);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Pelo erro, `user.list` não está definido. Como definiu essa função?

Comment: não esta definida..vou comentar

Comment: Não dá para entender assim. Você usa um objeto que não está definido, dá erro dizendo que não está definido e você não sabe o que está errado? :t

Comment: var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;

Comment: esse é o codigo do user.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara, você tá exportando os objetos que representam as funções de callback? Imagino que seja um objeto ou classe com nome de "customers", só que parece que ele não tá encontrando o mesmo. Se for isso, um "module.exports = customers" no arquivo que representa essas rotas resolveria.

Comment: Olá Thiago, seja bem vindo ao SOPT. Neste caso o ideal é fazer um comentário, a resposta só deve ser apresentada se ela for uma solução efetiva. Acesse o "Ajuda" para entender melhor como tratar perguntas e respostas aqui.

Comment: Olá Thiago. Apesar da sua resposta não ser apresentada, foi uma solução para mim. Obrigada.